I have some aggregated data in Python and want to visualize in a scatterplot/bar chart using pandas and matplotlib
Units Cost    Year Week Category
20224 100000  2023 24   Apple
30114 150000  2024 24   Orange
35000 175000  2023 15   Orange
10000 200000  2023 14   Apple

I want to show the sum of units, cost per unit by week. I am using below:
ax = df['Year'].value_counts().head(10).plot(kind = 'bar', title = 'Top years')
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
df.ax.set_ylabel('Years')

But this is only giving me the count of the number of years. I want to show
Sum(units) ---> 
NOT count(Year) ---> 


You are having that error "giving me the count of the number of years" because your x_axis_column_name must be a label or position:
Here is a code snippet to help:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming your data is stored in a dictionary
data = {
    'Units': [20224, 30114, 35000, 10000],
    'Cost': [100000, 150000, 175000, 200000],
    'Year': [2023, 2024, 2023, 2023],
    'Week': [24, 24, 15, 14],
    'Category': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Apple']
}

# Creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Aggregating the data by Year to get the sum of units
units_by_year = df.groupby('Year')['Units'].sum().reset_index()

# Plotting
ax = units_by_year.plot(kind='bar', x='Year', y='Units', title='Sum of Units by Year')
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Sum of Units')

plt.show()


